# What does the second parenthesis for the javascript pseudo protocol used in bookmarklet code, signify?

Tags: javascript

A bookmarklet has code in the following pattern -

```
javascript:(function(){})()
```

What does the second parenthesis signify? Please explain in the context of this snippet -

```
javascript: (function (d, w, f, t, e) {
    t = (e = w.elp$ || 0) ? clearInterval(e, d.title = odT, elp$ = 0) && 0 : f(w.elp$ = setInterval(function () {
        d.title = (new Date(f() - t)).toISOString().substr(11, 8)
    }, 40), w.odT = d.title)
})(document, window, function () {
    return (new Date()) | 0
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second set of parantheses is used to actually call the function that was just defined. In the case of your second snippet, it calls the function and passes in as parameters the document, the window and the new function it defines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For most bookmarklets, the second parenthesis is blank - it doesn't contain any parameters. 1) Does that mean, it should run whatever anonymous function is within the first parenthesis? 2) Three parameters are passed to the anonymous function but that function has 5 parameters and the code still works. How? What is the explanation for that? (the code snippet in the question is from the web, not mine)

Comment: 1.) It does, it'll just run without parameters. 2.) Yes, exactly that - the other parameters will just be `undefined`

Comment: Interesting. Another piece in the snippet that boggles me is how the clearInterval function has 3 parameters whereas the syntax of the clearInterval function allows for only one parameter?

Comment: Yes, that seems wrong. Where did you get the snippet from?

Comment: The code works & I like what it does. I got it from here - http://bookmarkletcollection.blogspot.in/2013/03/timetracker-bookmarklet.html

Comment: It'll just ignore the other arguments (there are ways at getting at all of the arguments passed into a function, regardless of signature), but they aren't doing anything.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53939/discussion-between-mvp-and-evan-knowles)

Comment: is it some sort of a undocumented trick that is being used as the code doesn't throw an error? are you aware of any cases similar to this or any resources that go into more detail. thanks for answering all questions..i appreciate it. What is the significance of the $ suffix in w.elp$ variable(?)